# How to convert value of ControlValueAccessor in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a `DatepickerComponent` but can't convert its value before returning it to its parent.
The `DatepickerComponent` implements `ControlValueAccessor` to use in a Reactive Form.

I need DateTime type for searching in server side. I want to send form.value to server side for searching.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker',
  templateUrl: './datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datepicker.component.scss'],
  providers: [{
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => Datepicker2Component),
      multi: true,
    },
  ]
})
export class DatepickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  public _value: any;
  onChange: any = (newValue) => {
  };
  onTouched: any = () => {
  };

  get value() {
    //can I convert this._value here?
    //before return it to parent
    return this._value;
  }
  set value(val) {
    this._value = val;
    this.onChange(val);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  writeValue(val) {
    if (val && val !== this._value) {
      this._value = val;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<dp-date-picker
  dir="rtl"
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  mode="day"
  theme="dp-material">
</dp-date-picker>
```

Comment: <dp-date-picker
      dir="rtl"
      [(ngModel)]="value"
      mode="day"
      theme="dp-material">
    </dp-date-picker>

Comment: I'm assuming the forwardRef of type `Datepicker2Component` is a typo?